# @Order in AbstractNameValueGatewayFilterFactory doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I have 2 classes: filter and class to get response body. As far as I know I need to specify order NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER-1 so filter will get response body.

But when I implement Ordered or use annotation @Order or via OrderedGatewayFilter I cann't call BodyRewrite class(which gets response body). When I try to use this for global filter(implemented GlobalFilter) it works fine.

May it be because I extend AbstractNameValueGatewayFilterFactory and I can't specify order for it?

Full code: https://github.com/artem-kurilko/NettyFilter

Jwt filter class:

```
@Component
public class JWTFilter extends AbstractNameValueGatewayFilterFactory {
    private final ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
    private final BodyRewrite bodyRewrite;

    @Autowired
    public JWTFilter(ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory, BodyRewrite bodyRewrite, ErrorWebExceptionHandler errorWebExceptionHandler) {
        this.modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory = modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
        this.bodyRewrite = bodyRewrite;
    }

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(NameValueConfig config) {
        System.out.println("\n          JWT FILTER\n");

        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> {
            GatewayFilter delegate = modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.apply(new ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                    .setRewriteFunction(byte[].class, byte[].class, bodyRewrite));
            return delegate.filter(exchange, chain).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println("\nPost JWTFilter executed\n")));
        }, NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER-1);
    }

}
```

Global filter:

```
@Component
public class ModifyResponseBodyFilter implements GlobalFilter, Ordered {
    private final ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
    private final BodyRewrite bodyRewrite;

    @Autowired
    public ModifyResponseBodyFilter(ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory, BodyRewrite bodyRewrite, ErrorWebExceptionHandler errorWebExceptionHandler) {
        this.modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory = modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory;
        this.bodyRewrite = bodyRewrite;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        if (exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath().equals("/key/login")) {
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }

        GatewayFilter delegate=modifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.apply(new ModifyResponseBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()
                .setRewriteFunction(byte[].class, byte[].class, bodyRewrite));
        return delegate.filter(exchange, chain).then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> System.out.println("\nPost GlobalFilter executed\n")));
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return NettyWriteResponseFilter.WRITE_RESPONSE_FILTER_ORDER-1;
    }
}
```

Class to receive response body:

```
@Component
class BodyRewrite implements RewriteFunction<byte[], byte[]> {

    @Override
    public Publisher<byte[]> apply(ServerWebExchange exchange, byte[] body) {
        String originalBody = body==null?"":new String(body);
        if (!ServerWebExchangeUtils.isAlreadyRouted(exchange)) {
            return Mono.just(originalBody.getBytes());
        } else {
            System.out.println("------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("got response body: " + originalBody);
            System.out.println("------------------------------------");

            return Mono.just(body);
        }
    }

}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: global_route
          uri: http://httbin.org
          predicates:
            - Path=/key/login
          filters:
            - JWTFilter=RSA512,HS512
        - id: global_route
          uri: http://httbin.org
          predicates:
            - Path=/**
          filters:
            - RewritePath=/service(?<segment>/?.*), $\{segment}
server:
  port: 8082
```

Output on jwt filter route

```
Stopped global filter as it is jwt filter route

Post JWTFilter executed
```

Output on global filter route

```
got response body: Something

Post GlobalFilter executed
```

So when I try to call BodyRewrite via JWTFilter it doesn't work, but with global filter it works correctly.

Comment: What does doesn't work mean?

Comment: I changed description it should be clear now, if not please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know GatewayFilter is used for a special route, so that you should bind it to a route.GlobalFilter will take effect for all routes.

And it's redundant that assembling a GatewayFilter with a GatewayFilter.

Comment: Not sure I understood your last sentence, but I specified route for gateway filter in application.yml, added code to description

Comment: hi, do you know what should be done to make jwtfilter get response body too?

Comment: I pasted your code in my pragram ,it worked well, and the response body was printed twice because of the two filters!Try to debug on the execution of all the filters!Cannot help you without reproduce.

Comment: I understand you, created repository with all my settings https://github.com/artem-kurilko/NettyFilter Still get this bug and don't know the reason

Comment: How about debugging into JWTFilter?Does the filter run?

Comment: I understood that these lines why the error happens, in global filter ``` if (exchange.getRequest().getURI().getPath().equals("/key/login")) {
            return exchange.getResponse().setComplete();
        }```

Comment: yes,i have tried and been confused about this code yesterday.If it runs, the other response filters will not run.

Comment: @ArtemiiKurilko ok,how?which way ?

Comment: kurilko365@gmail.com this is my mail you can write there